# anyone recognise this Jquery carousel plugin

Tags: jquery

Hi does anyone know the name of the plugin (if it is one) that powers the carousel on the home page of the camel back website. I have been looking through the code and can't find what makes the animation work like that. Thought I would ask on here as someone may recognise it.

[Camel back website](http://www.camelbak.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a custom code (which makes sense for a large site like theirs). You can study their widget in: http://www.camelbak.com/designs/camelbak/js/scripts.js starting on line 139

Comment: Thank you what I am trying to find is a plugin that will do the resize as the transition is happening

Comment: You can just use .animate() and resize and move at the same time.

Comment: Thats a great help. I a still very much a noob with javascript and jquery. No you have pointed me in the right direction thats great

Answer (score 0):

This website has some similar ones. http://www.webdesignshock.com/jquery-slideshow/